# XCode compilation of specific files

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any way to set up Xcode to only compile files that have been modified since the last build, getting this information from SVN for example? I have a huge project that takes a long time to compile. Trying to find a solution. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, Xcode is actually doing it by default! Remember that it has to compile and link everything. Unless you clean the project, it will try to reduce the amount of work as it is possible.